# Constraints for a Hadamard product to have rank 1

Tags: matrix-rank, constraints, positive-semidefinite, hadamard-product

I am looking for conditions to have a matrix $Z=X\oplus Y$, where $\oplus$ denotes the Hadamard product (with an abuse of notation), to have $rank(Z)=1$. Note that X and Y are both positive semi-definite matrices.

I know for instance that $rank(Z)\leq rank(X)rank(Y)$ and any real positive semi-definite rank-1 matrix $Z$ of size $n$ can be written as $Z=xx^T$, where $x$ is some vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. However, they do not really help.

Comment: A matrix $A$ has rank 1 iff $A=a\cdot b$ (Product of column and row vector), i.e., $A=(a_ib_j)$. Just a general comment.

Comment: Then, I add that X and Y are matrices. What does that mean for this general case?